# Combine two queries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, join, hql

In the first query, I need to have the count for each type regardless of whether that’s read or not (unread can be true or false). In the second query, I need the count for all types only for when unread is false. Currently I am calling the database two times, once for the first query and once for the second one. Is there anyway that I can call the database only once to get the results for both queries?

Please note that my queries are in HQL, I wrote the SQL version of them b/c I think its easier; so ideally I need to have a solution that works for HQL too. Thanks.

```
--Need the count regardless if is_read is true or false. 
--In order to get total of all rows, I add up each total for each group in the Java code:

select type_id as type, count(distinct ta.id) as totalId 
  from tableA as ta 
       inner join tableB tb on ta.id = tb.id 
       inner join tableC tc on tb.col1= tc.col2 
 where tc.col2= 6 
   and tb.is_deleted = 'N' 
 group by type_id
```

```
--Need the count only for is_read = false. 
--This query gives the total for all unread rows so no group by needed:
    
select count(distinct ta.id) as totalId 
  from tableA as ta 
       inner join tableB tb on ta.id =tb.id 
       inner join tableC tc on tb.col1 = tc.col2 
 where tc.col2= 6 
   and tb.is_deleted = 'N'
   and tb.is_read = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
SELECT 
ta.typeId AS type,
COUNT(DISTINCT ta.id) AS totalId,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tb.isRead = 'N' THEN ta.id END) AS unreadTotalId
FROM 
TableA ta 
INNER JOIN 
ta.tableB tb 
INNER JOIN 
tb.tableC tc  
WHERE 
tc.col2 = 6 AND tb.isDeleted = 'N' 
GROUP BY 
ta.typeId;
```

Comment: Your query is wrong - you aggregate both parts for ta.typeId, but originally the second query for total. I am not sure does HQL supports CTE, if not it ispoosible to CROSS JOIN second query

Comment: One of my original queries is wrong or the combined query? Would you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: (If that caused the confusion): It might be a bit more clear now that I added comments; in the first query, I also need the total count, but I do that in the Java code by adding up each total in the group by; in the second one, I just get the count. In the combined query, group by is used for both cases, so I add them up in the Java code.